# Evans PDE mappings into better spaces

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Evans PDE chapter 5.9 theorem 4 (mappings into better space), Evans wrote in the proof:

In addition, $\bar{u}^{'}\in L^2(0,T;L^2(V))$ , with the estimate:

\begin{equation}
||\bar{u}^{'}||_{L^2(0,T;L^2(V))}\leq C||u^{'}||_{L^2(0,T;L^2(U))}
\end{equation}

This follows if we consider difference quotients in the t-variable, remember the methods in 5.8.2, and observe also that $E$ is a bounded linear operator from $L^2(U)$ into $L^2(V)$.

Who can give some detail about this, I can't understand. Any suggestions may be helpful.

Thank all of you!

Answer (score 1):

From Theorem 3 (ii) in Section 5.8.2, we only need to show that
$$
\Vert D^h\bar{u}\Vert_{L^2(0,T;L^2(V))}\leq C\Vert u^{'}\Vert_{L^2(0,T;L^2(U))}.
$$
Since $\bar{u}=Eu$ and $E$ is a bounded linear operator,
$$
\Vert D^h\bar{u}\Vert_{L^2(0,T;L^2(V))}\leq C\Vert D^hu\Vert_{L^2(0,T;L^2(U))}.
$$
From Theorem 3 (i) in Section 5.8.2, we have
$$
\Vert D^hu\Vert_{L^2(0,T;L^2(U))}\leq C\Vert u^{'}\Vert_{L^2(0,T;L^2(U))}.
$$
The proof is completed by combining above two inequalities.